# Qgis: Fill a field depending from 2 others fields

Tags: qgis, python

I want to automatically fill a field based on the information from two others.

I have a column/field 1(integer) with values from 1 to 10...

...and, for each of those ten values in column 1, on the column 2 might appear 100 "different"/possible strings ( made up by associations like in the figure below)

[image: column 1]

I have to replace those 100, with 100 others,and i want the result to be written on a 3rd  new field/collumn

(for example, if i get 1 in collumn1 i want to have this replacement :"1 and 2" -> "YPC5 plus YPC6"...". And 100+ like this one. Each cell/possibility will have a match, but also each value that made up the association/string will have one and only one possible match. 1 will always be replaced by YPC5.s ( note: observe column 2, bellow)

[image: column2]
[image]

Comment: Seems to me the image doesn't fit the question?

Comment: Just edit, hope it helps making it more evident.

Comment: The second table has the replace values for the ones on the first table given.

The shapefile has 1 collumn with values from 1 to 10.

If I get 1 on the first collumn, I will get 1 table of 100 possible values ( values that might appear) in collumn 2 and that i have to replace with 100 matched strings, wich are there on the second table.

Comment: yes, on the 2nd table YES!

making it easier:

i'm automating a process that i have to do everyday.

could you help me doing it only for one possible value in collumn 1? this one value will generate a matrix of 100 posssible strings ( 1st screenshot) that i want to replace automatically for others 100 possible strings ( 2nd screenshot).

If i get this well i think i will make one script for each of the 10 values in collumn 1.

Comment: file format? i just have one shapefile and this exercise uses 3 different fields:
-1: values from 1 to 10
-2: 100 possible strings like those you have on table 1.
-3: 100 matches with wich i'll replace the 100 possible strings from field 2,

Comment: Answering this: "What file format is the first table? Is 1 in first table Always YPC5 "

Yes, but only if column 1 is equal 1. If we get a different value on column 1 ( 2 to 10), then we'll get different matches. table one ( possibilities) is the same, but matching values will vary..

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. For example, "1 in collumn1 i want to have this replacement :"1 and 2". Why "1 and 2", and not "1 and 3"? I think you should rewrite your question or it will probably be closed.

Comment: I've rewritten.Why? Because the replacement is one and only and what make the 100 replacements (matrix) vary is the value/index on column 1.
If I get '1' on the shapefile column 1, i'll ve to replace those values with matches from one matrix, and if i get '2', i'll have to replace the same values with values from another matrix.
Ex:
Getting 1 on shp coplumn/field 1:
"1 and 2" will be replaced by "YC5 plus YC6"
as "2 and 1" will be replaced by "YC6 plus YC5"
Getting 01 on shp coplumn/field 1:
"1 and 2" will be replaced by "YC7 plus YC8"
as "2 and 1" will be replaced by "YC8 plus YC7"

Comment: Your question is very confusing and unclear. Please try to provide a minimal example with reasonable column names and values (I don't think you actually have/want strings like "1 and 2" or "YC8 plus YC7"?). Show both the input and the desired result. IN QGIS.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4WzO.png

vertical -
shapefile column 1 values;

horizontal - 
part of column 2 strings.

All I want is replace the string '1 and 2' with matched values for 1 and 2 within the matrix. Thats why when I have '1 and 2' for column 1 equals 1, i get ' YC8 and YC8' and for column 1 equals 3, 'YC7 and YC7'.

When i'm referring to column is 'shapefile field 1'. '1 and 2' will appear on 'shapefile field 2', i want to write the replacement on 'shapefile field 3'.

Comment: Didn't you ask exactly this some time ago? I remember the question and that I answered

Comment: You did, on Aug 25 at 7:32.
But i didn't get it. I'm just a newbie in python.
See this, after make the replacement the string will still have algarisms and i'm afraid that those algarisms might be again replaced for a string like " 1 and 2" -> "YPC5 and YPC4" -> YPCYPC8 and YPCYPC7"...

I almost understood your comment... :) but should see the whole script. With this last matrix you get more data...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83446/discussion-on-question-by-rui-qgis-fill-a-field-depending-from-2-others-fields).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what the "Conditional" expressions can be used for. Depending on the context you can use `CASE` or `if`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't explain it well..

For each of those ten values in collumn 1, the collumn 2 is builded from a matrix of 100 associations like this...

 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 1 and 1 1 and 2 1 and 3 1 and 4 1 and 5 1 and 6 1 and 7 1 and 8 1 and 9 1 and 10
2 2 and 1 2 and 2 2 and 3 2 and 4 2 and 5 2 and 6 2 and 7 2 and 8 2 and 9 2 and 10

I have to replace those with 100 others.. depending on the first and second values i will get 2 different matches making up the final result. ( "1 and 2" -> " YV3 and YV6"...